# Half of my iCloud storage is full of nothing! (backups)

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, storage

I'm still on the 5gb iCloud free storage (I refuse to pay the 50gb Apple's monthly fee!), which I use mainly for important things cloud storage and iPhone backup, and I set it up to fit.

Last week my iPhone started to backup and, for some reason, his backup size double suddenly (from 1.3gb usual jumped to 2.5gb) and iCloud immediately notified everywhere that

> MY STORAGE IS FULL! WHY DON'T YOU UPGRADE?! IT'S ONLY 0.99€/MONTH!
> YOU'LL HAVE PLENTY OF BENEFITS! IT'S A BARGAIN!!

As it's not the first time it happens, I proceeded as usual: erase the actual back and make a new one but, for some reason, after I erased it, the 2.5gb are still occupied in my storage overall space

[image: Overall space]

but, as I hop into the backup, it's empty!

[image: Backup detail]

It was a week ago, I tried to wait a while to see if it fix by itself (even if it takes something like 5 seconds to notify that my storage was full!) but nope: after a week, I still have 2.5gbs full of nothing?

What can I do?
Is there any way to see the raw files into my iCloud storage?

EDIT: [Rumming in the support](https://support.apple.com/en-euro/HT204247), I may have found the problem:

> iCloud backups are available for 180 days after you disable or stop using iCloud Backup.

so, apparently, my backup will survive in my storage FOR 6 MONTHS without having any chance to delete it manually before or any chance to restore it, it's just occupying my storage for nothing. Am I right?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem where I enabled iCloud Backup for a device, but the backup never completed, and I disabled it but the space of the backup was reserved. I contacted Apple Support who recognised the problem and said the same thing that it would free after 6 months, but escalated it to someone who could purge the space manually. They did while I waited on the phone, and I saw the space free immediately.

Comment: You're right, I tried again with Apple support (via phone instead of chat) and worked! After 25 mins of call (that's why I prefer the chat!) they fixed it. Looks like the "iCloud specialist team" has a button to force the system to recalculate the space allocation. Thanks for your experience!